# MySql GROUP BY + IN performance

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I had a query like that (actually, it's part of a complex query. However, I extracted it to just show the problem which I have)

```
SELECT
  bar.foo, count(1)
FROM
  bar
WHERE
  bar.baz in ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
GROUP BY
  bar.foo;
```

The problem with this query is that it is "Using temporary; Using filesort"

I have an index on bar.baz. However, it looks like it doesn't help, because of IN operator.

I saw in couple of places recommendation in such case to break down it to multiple queries with simple where statement (bar.baz = 1) and use JOIN. However, it won't work for me, because these "1", "2" etc are actually returned by a subquery.

I am curios. Is there a way to avoid filesort here?

Answer (score 1):

I found this tip at the link below:

```
SELECT
bar.foo, count(1)
FROM
bar
WHERE
bar.baz in ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
GROUP BY
bar.foo
ORDER BY NULL;
```

http://dev.housetrip.com/2013/04/19/mysql-order-by-null/